# Neo4j/Cypher Import a CSV file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV file, which have 11 columns : Rank, Year, Name...
It contains the best video games sales. I'm new to neo4j and cypher.

I am trying to import it to neo4j with this cypher query :
`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///vgsales.csv' AS line CREATE (:Vgsales {rank: toInteger(line.Rank), name: line.Name, platform: line.Platform, year: toInteger(line.Year), genre: line.Genre, publisher: line.Publisher, NA_sales: toInteger(line.NA_Sales), EU_sales: toInteger(line.EU_Sales)], JP_sales: toInteger(line.JP_Sales), Other_sales: toInteger(line.Other_Sales), Global_sales: toInteger(line.Global_Sales)})`

When i do this, I have the nodes, but there is no reationships between them, and I need to give the graph model with this query : call db.schema.visualization but there is only one empty node when I do this.

I don't understand why there isn't any relationships .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error on your script. You can remove this line below:

```
WITH v
```

I tried it on my neo4j browser and it works well:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///vgsales.csv' AS line 
CREATE(v:Vgsales {rank: toInteger(line.Rank), name: line.Name, platform: line.Platform, year:toInteger(line.Year)}) 
//WITH v  <- remove this!
MERGE (g:GENRE {genre: line.Genre}) 
MERGE (p:PUBLISHER {publisher: line.Publisher, NA_sales: toInteger(line.NA_Sales), 
EU_sales: toInteger(line.EU_Sales), JP_sales: toInteger(line.JP_Sales), Other_sales: toInteger(line.Other_Sales), Global_sales: toInteger(line.Global_Sales)}) 
MERGE (v)-[:IN_GENRE]->(g) 
MERGE (p)-[:PUBLISHED]->(v) 

Result: Added 3 labels, created 3 nodes, set 11 properties, created 2 relationships, completed after 235 ms.
```

Comment: Thx, It worked. Do you know how I can determine the In degree and the out degree and the total degree of each node of the graph.  Also, the longest path of the graph so the diameter of the graph and the density of the graph. And the two last questions, are the number of relations per type, and the number of nodes per label so for each label.

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer, please accept and upvote it . Thanks. Then create another question for getting the degree. Btw, is this a school homework?

Comment: It's the first time I use stack overflow, I accepted your answer now and yes It's a school homework.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer.
I'm posting back the query because there was an ']' that i forgot to remove :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///vgsales.csv' AS line CREATE(v:Vgsales {rank: toInteger(line.Rank), name: line.Name, platform: line.Platform, year:toInteger(line.Year)}) WITH v MERGE (g:GENRE {genre: line.Genre}) MERGE (p:PUBLISHER {publisher: line.Publisher, NA_sales: toInteger(line.NA_Sales), EU_sales: toInteger(line.EU_Sales), JP_sales: toInteger(line.JP_Sales), Other_sales: toInteger(line.Other_Sales), Global_sales: toInteger(line.Global_Sales)}) MERGE (v)-[:IN_GENRE]->(g) MERGE (p)-[:PUBLISHED]->(v)
```

However the query still doesn't work. I have this error : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKWRa.png)

This is how my dataset looks like : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoeBh.png)

The exercise that I must do for tomorrow is to find a dataset, to find a problematic and to answer it with a plugin algorithm and then get the graph model and load the csv file in neo4j but i don't know how should add the relationships between the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems like you have not created any relationship just a single node for each row in your csv.
My suggesion is try to create a model first. you can use arrows.app to try and describe your model.

Relationships are created by joining two nodes lets say

```
CREATE (:PERSON {name:"CHARLIE")-[:FOLLOWS]->(:PERSON {name:"JOHN"})
```

And from your code id probably try something like

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///vgsales.csv' AS line CREATE(v:Vgsales {rank: toInteger(line.Rank), name: line.Name, platform: line.Platform, year: toInteger(line.Year)}) WITH v MERGE (g:GENRE {genre: line.Genre}) MERGE (p:PUBLISHER {publisher: line.Publisher, NA_sales: toInteger(line.NA_Sales), EU_sales: toInteger(line.EU_Sales)], JP_sales: toInteger(line.JP_Sales), Other_sales: toInteger(line.Other_Sales), Global_sales: toInteger(line.Global_Sales)}) MERGE (v)-[:IN_GENRE]->(g) MERGE (p)-[:PUBLISHED]->(v)
```

---

I'm not sure that fits your model though you could try and draw your model and perhaps i will write a better code.

---